# Mysql_connect(): Too many connections

Tags: php, mysql

Возможно ли при возникающей ошибке на сайте:

> mysql_connect(): Too many connections in ...

перенаправлять на др страницу (типа: слишком много подключений подожди и рефреш с таймером)
Есть ли какие нибудь другие решения?
Что мне даст @ перед коннектом, не подключение к базе? (не получилось поймать)

> Aborted_connects 839058 
> Connections 22353786 
> Max_used_connections 201
> max_connections 200
> max_user_connections 3 
> Threads_connected 7

Comment: [depricated](http://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.mysql-connect.php)

    Данное расширение устарело, начиная с версии PHP 5.5.0, и будет 
    удалено в будущем. Используйте вместо него MySQLi или PDO_MySQL. 
    Смотрите также инструкцию MySQL: выбор API и соответствующий FAQ 
    для получения более подробной информации. Альтернативы для данной 
    функции:

[mysqli_connect()](http://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.mysqli-connect.php)

[PDO::__construct()](http://www.php.net/manual/ru/pdo.construct.php)

Comment: Спасибо! Давно заглядываюсь на PDO, нужно приступать... Не раз ловил себя на мысли, что это удобней во многих вопросах.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**@** - подавляет вывод ошибок, т.е. поставив собачку перед **mysql_connect()** вы не увидете - **Too many connections** 
Можно сделать так:

```
$my_connect = mysql_connect("host", "user", "password") or die("Ошибка соединения: " . mysql_error());
print ("Успешное соединение с базой");
```

Можно воспользоваться функцией **Sleep()**, передать ей в качестве параметра сколько нужно ждать и выполнить свои действия. 
Например

```
if (!$my_connect) sleep(10);//задержка на 10 сек.   
reconnect(); //переконектится (пользовательская функция)
```

Comment: Тоесть если я поставлю собаку то крита не будет показано и подключения к базе тоже не будет?

Comment: собачка просто глушит вывод сообщения в браузер, но не более. Но подключению к базе это не поможет.

Comment: У меня уже стоит    

    mysql_connect("host", "user", "password") or die("Could not connect to MySQL server!");

Comment: надо не die делать а какой-нить 

    header("Location: defer.php");exit;

Comment: Это будет работать?

Comment: ну надо ещё defer.php написать, который будет пытаться перегрузить referer через интервал, может быть нужно ещё как-то POST data сохранить....